# Is it safe to do an empty while loop inside a for loop?

Tags: c#

I'm curious if it's safe to do an empty while loop inside a for loop, in order to stop it from continuing until x is true?

For example (updated to a downloading example):

```
string[] links = new string[3] {"http://url.com/download1.rar", "http://url.com/download2.rar", "http://url.com/download3.rar"};

public void download(String link) {
   // download link
   x = false;
}
```

and then later somewhere

```
for (int i; i < links.length; i++) {
   download(links[i]);
   x = true;
   while (x) {
     // Do nothing so the for loop basically freezes until download is finished
   }

   // Do something else or just end it here and continue the loop
}
```

Please note: This is a simple example, downloading has absolutely nothing to do with the question, I'm just trying to help you help me make sense of this

Or is there a better way for this to be done?

Edit: edited the code to show a better example of what I was thinking

Comment: I think it will get stuck in there, try adding a `break;` statement to make sure it will get out of the while loop.

Comment: What "this" is to be done? This construction makes sense for multi-threading apps, but multi-threading has lots of better ways to wait for a separate job finished: mutex, semaphores etc.

Comment: What code do you expect will make x true while this code is looping forever?  How is that code running?

Comment: And how is `x` declared? (Is it a property with appropriate memory barriers? A volatile variable?)

Comment: No need to overcomplicate things guys, it's a simple question

Comment: @JohnK The problem is multi-threading is not a simple problem, so you can't have a simple question on it.

Comment: @Kalmino I did not downvote the question, but I thought it was pretty obious the OP was talking about multi-threading. Otherwise why would he talk about `x` changing when he was not changing it in the loop.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry, the downvote comment was a general question, not directed at you.  And yes, I assume he means multi-threading as well but it was never explicitly stated and given the "it's a simple question" comment from the OP, I wasn't sure of their intent.

Comment: @JohnK your update totally changes the question (just noticed it), now it looks like you are expecting `x` to change some how while you are spinning inside the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Update totally changes the question.

If you are updating `x` in the loop and it is not being changed from a external thread your program will lock up and will not continue because your code can't reach the `x = true` because it is being blocked by the while loop.

---

That is going to use up 100% of the CPU on a single core performing 0 useful work, do you consider that ok? Also, if `x` is not marked volitile it may spin forever, even if you update `x`.

A much better way is use some kind of mutex to block the code till you are ready. For example a [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private ManualResetEventSlim _block = new ManualResetEventSlim();

public void A()
{
    for (int i; i < args.length; i++) 
    {
       _block.Wait(); //This code blocks till UnblockA() is called.

       // Do something
    }
}

public void UnblockA()
{
    _block.Set();
}

public void BlockA()
{
    _block.Reset();
}
```

Comment: I updated the question, would you mind taking another look again?

Comment: Well looking at your updated code it looks like `download(` does not return until it has finished downloading so the while loop is pointless, it already does not continue because your function call is blocking. I reccomend starting a new question with a complete compilable example of you what you are trying to do and explain why it is not working.

Comment: I'm not doing anything, so there's nothing really that "is not working" here, I'm just (as stated in the topic) trying to make sense of this, because it's kinda confusing me when I think about it :-)

Comment: Well you will only get yourself more confused if you don't use [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you ask your question.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: No, this is not universally safe. See the section "Memory Barriers and Volatility" in this excellent set of articles on threading in .NET: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility

Specifically:

"Do We Really Need Locks and Barriers?

Working with shared writable fields without locks or fences is asking for trouble. There’s a lot of misleading information on this topic — including the MSDN documentation which states that MemoryBarrier is required only on multiprocessor systems with weak memory ordering, such as a system employing multiple Itanium processors. We can demonstrate that memory barriers are important on ordinary Intel Core-2 and Pentium processors with the following short program. You’ll need to run it with optimizations enabled and without a debugger (in Visual Studio, select Release Mode in the solution’s configuration manager, and then start without debugging):

```
static void Main()
{
  bool complete = false; 
  var t = new Thread (() =>
  {
    bool toggle = false;
    while (!complete) toggle = !toggle;
  });
  t.Start();
  Thread.Sleep (1000);
  complete = true;
  t.Join();        // Blocks indefinitely
}
```

This program never terminates because the complete variable is cached in a CPU register. Inserting a call to Thread.MemoryBarrier inside the while loop (or locking around reading complete) fixes the error."

And later:

"As it happens, Intel’s X86 and X64 processors always apply acquire-fences to reads and release-fences to writes — whether or not you use the volatile keyword — so this keyword has no effect on the hardware if you’re using these processors. However, volatile does have an effect on optimizations performed by the compiler and the CLR — as well as on 64-bit AMD and (to a greater extent) Itanium processors. This means that you cannot be more relaxed by virtue of your clients running a particular type of CPU.

(And even if you do use volatile, you should still maintain a healthy sense of anxiety, as we’ll see shortly!)"